# Why does the manifest file have no effect

Tags: c++, manifest, photoshop

I tried to open photoshop.exe using C++, but photoshop.exe.manifest did not take effect. If you manually double-click to open photoshop.exe file that shows normal working.

The registry has set and reboot system:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SideBySide]
"PreferExternalManifest"=dword:00000001
```

Maybe it's the path?

[image: photoshop]

```
TCHAR szCommandLineName[200]= _T("Photoshop.exe");
TCHAR szCommandLinePath[200] = _T("F:\\Program Files\\Adobe Photoshop 2020\\");
TCHAR szCommandLine[200] = _T("F:\\Program Files\\Adobe Photoshop 2020\\Photoshop.exe");

TCHAR buf[1000];
GetCurrentDirectory(1000, buf);   
TRACE(_T("Current Directory:%s\n"), buf);

 SetCurrentDirectory(szCommandLinePath);
//::WinExec("F:\\Program Files\\Adobe Photoshop 2020\\Photoshop.exe", SW_SHOW);
//ShellExecuteW(NULL, _T("open"), _T("photoshop.exe.bat"), NULL, szCommandLinePath, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
//return;

// system("photoshop.exe");
// return;
STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof(si) };
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW | STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
//si.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;
si.wShowWindow = TRUE;
BOOL bRet = ::CreateProcess(
    szCommandLine,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    FALSE,  //bInheritHandles
    NULL,   //dwCreationFlags
    NULL,   //lpEnvironment
    NULL,//lpCurrentDirectory
    &si,
    &pi);
int nError = GetLastError();

::CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
::CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);

return ;
```

Answer (score 1):

As noted in a comment by the OP:

> I found the reason, Because it's 32 bits build.The registry should
> have
> `Wow6432Node`:
> `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SideBySide] "PreferExternalManifest"=dword:00000001`
>
> liang gong  Apr 16, 2020 at 2:16